# AWS pinpoint - Receive message from short code

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, aws-pinpoint

I am not able to receive SMS from `short code` numbers on AWS Pinpoint.
When I send an SMS to my pinpoint number from a `long code` number it works fine.
When I send an SMS to my pinpoint number from a `short code` number I do not receive it.

I have not found anything about it in the documentation.

**Does anyone know how to receive SMS coming from a `short code` number being sent to my AWS pinpoint number?**

Comment: Same for me. Do you have a solution ? It's the same with Twilio

Comment: From my research, seems like you cannot receive short codes on the voice over ip kind of phones that AWS or Twilio offers.